# GetMapAsync is not being called for HuaweiMap

Tags: android, kotlin, huawei-map-kit

I want to show a map of type `HuaweiMap` on a Huawei device. I have the following code where  `SupportMapFragment` is from `com.huawei.hms.maps`, but when I debug it `getMapAsync` it doesn't get called. I have the same method for `GoogleMap` and it works fine. Does anyone knows why that might happen?

```
  val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as? SupportMapFragment

  private fun displayMap(mapFragment: SupportMapFragment?, context: Context) {
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync {
        map = it           //this part is never reached
        refreshMap?.visibility = View.GONE
        it.clear()
        locationDrawUtil = LocationDrawUtil(it)
        locationDrawUtil!!.clear()
        it.mapType = HuaweiMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
        it.uiSettings.isMapToolbarEnabled = true
        centerMapOnMyLocation(context)
        locationDrawUtil!!.showMapLayers(context, it)
        onMapReady()
    }
}
```

Libraries that I use:

```
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:6.7.0.300'
huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:6.6.1.301'
```